# How to add and editable combo box in a Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In a Razor page, I need to have a combobox that permit the user to either select or type a value.
The combobox is loaded from the database.
I'm using NET 8.0.

Extract of the page chtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="TransactionLine.Payee" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="TransactionLine.Payee" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PayeeName"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="TransactionLine.Payee" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Extract for the model

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
    ...
    ViewData["PayeeName"] = new SelectList(_payeesService.GetPayees(), "Name", "Name");
    TransactionLine = transactionLine;
    return Page();
}
```

How can I make the combo box editable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try use `<input>` with `<datalist>`

```
@{

    List<string> namelist = new List<string>{"Tom","John","Nancy"};
}

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"></label>
    <input  class="form-control" list="payeenames"></input>
    <datalist id="payeenames">
        @foreach (var item in namelist)
        {
            <option>@item</option>
        }
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Result
[image]